# How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am trying to upgrade package of scikit-learn from 0.16 to 0.17. For that I am trying to use binaries from this website: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn. I have Windows 7 x64 bit. I downloaded the relevant package locally and gave following commands and got Requirement already up-to-date:

```
C:\Users\skumar>pip install --upgrade --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=../../
SOURCE/APPS scikit-learn
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

Then I tried to upgrade it from remote site and got similar result:

```
C:\Users\skumar>pip install --upgrade --use-wheel --no-index --trusted-host www.
lfd.uci.edu --find-links=http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ scikit-learn

Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

On Remote site there are two versions i.e., 0.16 & 0.17. Is there a way to specify version in command? Or how do you install/upgrade wheel file?

Answer (score 43):

Anaconda comes with the `conda` package manager which is designed to handle these kinds of upgrades. Start by updating conda itself to get the most recent package lists:

```
conda update conda
```

And then install the version of scikit-learn you want

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.17
```

All necessary dependencies will be upgraded as well. If you have trouble with conda on Windows, there are some relevant FAQ here: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq

Comment: Thanks. I did that and when I executed "import sklearn" then I got this error: DLL load failed: Access is denied. Then I uninstalled sklearn by command conda remove scikit-learn and installed it again. I am still getting this error. I am using Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)|

Comment: You probably have a permissions issue in the directory where anaconda is installed: you should make sure users have read/execute permissions.

Comment: ``conda activate environment_name`` followed by ``conda update scikit-learn``

Answer (score 13):

#### Following Worked for me for scikit-learn on Anaconda-Jupyter Notebook.

Upgrading my scikit-learn from 0.19.1 to 0.19.2 in anaconda installed on Ubuntu on Google VM instance:

#### Run the following commands in the terminal:

First, check existing available packages with versions by using:

```
conda list
```

It will show different packages and their installed versions in the output. Here check for scikit-learn. e.g. for me, the output was:

```
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36hedc7406_0
```

Now I want to Upgrade to 0.19.2 July 2018 release i.e. latest available version.

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
conda install scikit-learn=0.19.2
```

As you are trying to upgrade to 0.17 version try the following command:

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.17
```

Now check the required version of the scikit-learn is installed correctly or not by using:

```
conda list
```

For me the Output was:

```
scikit-learn              0.19.2          py36_blas_openblasha84fab4_201  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
```

#### Note: Don't use pip command if you are using Anaconda or Miniconda

I tried following commands:

```
!conda update conda 
!pip install -U scikit-learn
```

It will install the required packages also will show in the `conda list` but  if you try to import that package it will not work.

On the website [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html](http://Installing%20scikit-learn) it is mentioned as:
Warning To upgrade or uninstall scikit-learn installed with Anaconda or conda you should not use the pip.

Answer (score 11):

So to upgrade scikit-learn package, you have to follow below process

**Step-1:** Open your terminal(**Ctrl+Alt+t**)

**Step-2:** Now for checking currently installed packages along with the 
             versions installed on your 
        conda environment by typing `conda list`

**Step-3:** Now for upgrade type below command

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 6):

**Updating a Specific Library - `scikit-learn`:**

***Anaconda (`conda`):***

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

***Pip Installs Packages (`pip`):***

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

***Verify Update:***

```
conda list scikit-learn
```

It should now display the current (and desired) version of the `scikit-learn` library.

For me personally, I tried using the `conda` command to update the `scikit-learn` library and it acted as if it were installing the latest version to then later discover (with an execution of the `conda list scikit-learn` command) that it was the same version as previously and never updated (or recognized the update?). When I used the `pip` command, it worked like a charm and correctly updated the `scikit-learn` library to the latest version!

Hope this helps!

More in-depth details of latest version can be found here (be mindful this applies to the `scikit-learn` library version of `0.22`):

- [Release Highlights for scikit-learn 0.22](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_22_0.html)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using conda. Conda is an anconda specific package manager. If you want to know more about conda, read [the conda docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/faq.html).

Using conda in the command line, the command below would install scipy 0.17.

```
conda install scipy=0.17.0
```

Comment: When I did this and wrote a simple statement import sklearn I am getting this error: DLL load failed, Access is denied. The reason given is something like this: ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 2))

Comment: Like @jakedvp mentioned in his comment, you need to make sure you have the correct permissions set for your anaconda directory. To check this, go to the directory containing anaconda and type `ls -l`. Find anaconda and look at the left most column where permissions are defined for user, groups, and others. It should look something like this `drwxr-xr-x`. What you should care about are the first the characters, these are your permissions for that directory as a user.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work to update to 0.24.1, on Windows 10 64bits, so I share the way I did it with the GUI:

1. launch Anaconda3 gui
2. on the left menu, click "environments"
3. next to "base (root)", click on the green arrow/triangle
4. select "Open Terminal"
5. type the command line:

   conda install scikit-learn==0.24.1

It worked without error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter in anaconda, after `conda update scikit-learn` in terminal, close anaconda and restart, otherwise the error will occur again.