# AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv_results_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to apply this code :

```
pipe = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5), LogisticRegression())
param_grid = {'logisticregression__C': [ 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100],
              "tfidfvectorizer__ngram_range": [(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3)]} 

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5)
grid.fit(text_train, Y_train)

scores = grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'].reshape(-1, 3).T
# visualize heat map
heatmap = mglearn.tools.heatmap(
scores, xlabel="C", ylabel="ngram_range", cmap="viridis", fmt="%.3f",
xticklabels=param_grid['logisticregression__C'],
yticklabels=param_grid['tfidfvectorizer__ngram_range'])
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
```

But I have this error :

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv_results_'
```

Comment: What version of python/sklearn are you using?

Comment: Python's Version  3.5.2 but when i check sklearn version : 0.0.
Sklearn updates automatically when i update scikit-learn ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved ! 
Uninstall and install **conda scikit learn** in 0.18.1 [How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679938/how-to-upgrade-scikit-learn-package-in-anaconda).

When I import GridSearch :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

Answer (score 25):

Update your scikit-learn, `cv_results_` has been introduced in 0.18.1, earlier it was called `grid_scores_` and had slightly different structure http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV

Comment: I don't understand.. When I check my version in Pycharm, I have version 0.18.1. I try to update it : 
1) conda update conda  and 2) conda install scikit-learn=0.18.1
But I have the same error

Comment: Clearly this is not python that is being used by your IDE, but this is not python related issue but with your configuration. Lack of this field can be caused only by the old version of sklearn.

Answer (score 6):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

use this `clf.cv_results_`

Comment: This has already been addressed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558108/4685471) 2 years before your post, after upgrading scikit-learn as suggested in the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41527345/4685471) above (which you fail to address); please do not add duplicate answers.

Answer (score -7):

First, you should update your sklearn, using:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

After that, check if you are include the wrong module:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

Change to new path:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```