# AttributeError when use CV_Score_ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, operators

> **AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv_scores_'**

This error appear, when I use the following code so what can i do to resolve it. 
I use the latest version of python

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import reshape
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
import csv
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import operator
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from operator import itemgetter
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
clf = GridSearchCV(RFR, parameters)
clf.fit(mov[num_cat_key_feat],labels)
# Utility function to report best scores
def report(grid_scores, n_top=3):
    top_scores = sorted(grid_scores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n_top]
    for i, score in enumerate(top_scores):
        print("Rank: {0}".format(i + 1))
        print("Mean validation score: {0:.3f} (std: {1:.3f})".format(
              score.mean_validation_score,
              np.std(score.cv_validation_scores)))
        print("Parameters: {0}".format(score.parameters))
        print("")
report(clf.cv_scores_)
```

Comment: Please update your code to explicitly show your **imports** and the definition of `clf`.

Comment: okay look for update

Comment: -desertnaut  is this what you want?

Comment: which version of the sklearn are you using?

Comment: @Mirodil dunno i install the package using terminal pip install sklearn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv\_results\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524565/attributeerror-gridsearchcv-object-has-no-attribute-cv-results)

Comment: @AI_Learning i could not understand

Comment: Run these two lines, import sklearn            
sklearn.__version__  and check your version of sklearn

Comment: @AI_Learning this is the version 0.20.2

Comment: You might get this error, if you try to access cv_results_ without fitting the data. Hence, make sure you fit the data before calling this. I can see that you are doing it rightly in the given code. Do cross check

Comment: yes i use it rightly

Comment: It seems to me you are using older code try the following code:
`
for i, score in enumerate(clf.cv_results_['mean_score_time']):
    print("Rank: {0}".format(i + 1))
    print("Mean validation score: {0:.3f} (std: {1:.3f})".format(
        clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'][i],
        clf.cv_results_['std_test_score'][i] ))
    print("Parameters: {0}".format(clf.cv_results_['params'][i]))
    print("")
`