# Grid Search attributes were showing as they were not part of that method

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am trying to perform hyper parameter tuning of logistic regression and SGDClassifier with "log loss" using GridSearchCV method. But upon printing the best_score_, best_params_ attributes am getting an error as they were not part of the GridSearchCV method. And I have the updated scikit package (0.20.3) installed. Couldnt able to find out the reason? or am I making an error with  multiple models initiation on Grid Search method? Any guidelines would be helpful?

I have reinstalled sklearn package to the newest one but still no help!

Am trying to check the logistic model performance on both LogisticRegression() method and SGDClassifier() with log loss, so understand how well the Stochastic Gradient Descent creates a difference in metric results. Below are code snippet:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

estimator = [logr_w2v, sgd_lr_w2v]

para = {'C' : [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000], 'alpha' : [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000]}

Grid_w2v = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid = para, scoring = 'f1', n_jobs= 4, refit = True , cv = 5)

GridSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise-deprecating',
       estimator=[LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=1000, multi_class='warn', n_jobs=4,
          penalty='l1', random_state=50, solver='saga', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False), SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, ...dom_state=50, shuffle=True, tol=0.001,
       validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=0, warm_start=False)],
       fit_params=None, iid='warn', n_jobs=4,
       param_grid={'C': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000], 'alpha': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 100, 1000]},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring='f1', verbose=0)

hyperparameter = []


for i in range(len(estimator)):

    Grid_w2v.estimator[i].fit(x1_w2v, y_true)

    hyperparameter.append((Grid_w2v.estimator[i]).best_params_)

    print("the best score value on each estimator is: ",Grid_w2v.best_score_)
```

I was expecting that the above loop will save hyper parameters from both Logisitic Regression and SGDClassifier in the hyperparameter. But I was getting the below error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b53708a5f29e> in <module>()
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_score_'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'cv\_results\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524565/attributeerror-gridsearchcv-object-has-no-attribute-cv-results)

Comment: Yeah! I even seen that post. And i have updated the package to latest version (even uninstall and install again as well). But still the problem persists.

Comment: What is the motivation for having two different models inside a GridSearchCV object? Can't you run the two separately and then keep the best of the two? All your difficulties come from the combination of two models in the same GridSearchCV

Comment: @MaximeKan That's Correct! I can tune the models separately and compare their performances. But my question now is does the GridSearchCV() will allow us to tune multiple models inherently? or there is no way to do it!