# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.compose'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to import this

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
```

but getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.compose'

My scikit-learn package version is 0.19.1 in anaconda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sklearn.compose` is not available in scikit-learn v0.19; it was introduced in v0.20. From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

> *New in version 0.20.*

You can also confirm from the [list of modules](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/classes.html) for v0.19 that there is not a `sklearn.compose` module.

You should upgrade to the latest scikit-learn version (currently 0.20.3) by running

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

from your command prompt (see the [package page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn) at Anaconda cloud or the SO thread [How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679938/how-to-upgrade-scikit-learn-package-in-anaconda) for more options).