# scikit-learn.impute isn't being imported from Imputer via Spyder using the code from Machine Learning A-Z tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, spyder, python-3.7

My code isn't working that I copied word for word from the Machine Learning A-Z™: Hands-On Python & R In Data Science tutorial course. I am using Python 3.7, I have installed the scikit-learn package in my environment. It isn't working, I have tried looking for a package that has sklearn although it doesn't seem to find anything. It is giving me this error.
I am running my environment through Anaconda.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (C:\Users\vygan\.conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd



# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = pd.DataFrame(dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values)
y = pd.DataFrame(dataset.iloc[:, 3].values)

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: `Imputer` has been been deprecated and now should be replaced by `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer` instead, as mentioned by @parsa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it moved permanently from preprocessing to impute library, u can call it like:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

it's quite the same.
if it doesn't work, you should uninstall it with pip and then install it again
it may not installed properly for the first time

it doesn't have axis anymore but you could easily handle it with pandas dataframe header like this:

```
si=SimpleImputer()
si.fit([dataset["headername"]])
```

there is a strategy parameter that let you choose between "mean", "most_frequent","median" and "constant"

but there is another imputer that I like more:

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
```

which will impute missing values with an average of k nearest neighbors

Comment: this worked for me. I'm not sure if I should make another question although now I am getting a ```TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'``` It seems as if it doesn't recognize my axis = 0 argument.

Comment: I couldn't say it in a comment so I edited my answer

Comment: ``` File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc ```     ```TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 3, None))' is an invalid key ```

Comment: ```from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
si = SimpleImputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean')
si = SimpleImputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = si.transform(X[:, 1:3])``` This is how I revised my code based on your answer. I am unsure if I did a good job. You have answered the original question and I will be moving my new issue to a separate post.

Answer (score 2):

**A more complete answer:**

`Imputer` (https://sklearn.org/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html`)
can be found only in versions 0.19.1 and below.

`SimpleImputer` appeared at the latest versions and this is what you need.

---

Try to install the latest version:

```
 pip install -U scikit-learn # or using conda
```

And then use:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

Source: https://github.com/mindsdb/lightwood/issues/75

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Which sklearn version do you have?

```py
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

> '0.21.3'

You can upgrade packages with conda in the following way:

[How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679938/how-to-upgrade-scikit-learn-package-in-anaconda/33680217)

Comment: Where will I type import sklearn to get the version? My anaconda prompt doesn't allow me to. Says import is not recognizable.

Comment: Adding a piece of code would be good for better understanding of what you are referring.

You should import packages at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem because the library was changed from `preprocessing` to `impute` and the class was changed to `SimpleImputer` from `Imputer`.

I changed my code as follows:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
simp = SimpleImputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean')
simp = SimpleImputer().fit(X[:, 1:3]) 
X[:, 1:3] = simp.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```