# How to update Pandas in Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, conda

I want to use the compare() function available in Pandas 1.1.0.  I am doing an update in Anaconda to Pandas, but it just takes me to 0.25?

Comment: Did you try `pip install --upgrade pandas` in conda prompt?

Comment: first run `conda update conda ` and then `conda update pandas'

Comment: @Sociopath I thought it was bad to mix pip and conda?

Comment: @smackenzie it is. don't do it unless the package you're looking for is not available in conda.

Comment: which version of python is your environment using?

Comment: @PaulH 3.7.4 version

Comment: @Sociopath took me to 0.25 again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade scikit-learn package in anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679938/how-to-upgrade-scikit-learn-package-in-anaconda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas hasn't released `v1.1.0` as of now, current [`PyPI`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) latest version is `v1.0.5`

Recently pandas released *first release candidate* you can install this pandas version [`v1.1.0rc0`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.1.0rc0) using

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --pre pandas==1.1.0rc0
```

Please go thorough [`Pandas 1.1.0rc0`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.1.0rc0)

One more way is to clone the [`pandas-dev/pandas`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/master) repo locally and build it locally pandas has good resource go thorough [`Creating development environment`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/development/contributing.html#creating-a-development-environment)

After successfully building, you can check by doing this.

Open python and import pandas

```
import pandas as pd

pd.__version__
# '1.1.0rc0+2.g3e88e170a' # my build version.
```

Note:

> `pd.__version__` is different for everyone if you are building from GitHub locally.

If you have any queries regarding development of pandas they have an active Gitter channel [**`pandas`**](https://gitter.im/pydata/pandas#)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
`conda install pandas=1.1.0`.
You may need to add a channel that contains pandas 1.1.0.
Conda forge contains pandas 1.0.5
`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pandas=1.1.0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

Answer (score 0):

Typing `conda update pandas` should do the job.

Comment: does the job in that it took me from 0.24 to 0.25!!

Comment: Yes, see my response

Comment: Updating pandas is constricted by

anaconda -> requires pandas==0.25.1=py37ha925a31_0

Comment: maybe you could try reinstalling anaconda